# How to change the function plot colour in Grapher and make it persistent?

Tags: settings, grapher, macos

Here's `y=x^2` plotted in blue:

[image: x^2]

I coloured the function by going to "Window > Show Inspector".

So all is nice and smooth, but when I change the function to, say, `y=x^3`, the plot turns black and has an the width of 1.0 again:

[image: x^3]

How to keep the style of the function object the same, even if I change its parameters?